# Crashed: WebThread

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am getting a lot of reports on Crashlytics of this WebThread crash, mostly for iPads (~80%) on iOS 12 (~96%). Not sure exactly what it means aside from being a timer / timing issue - any ideas? I have Amazon Ads, Google AdMob and use a WkWebView for the main app.

```
Crashed: WebThread
0  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x1d0eb5fe4 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient
1  AGXGLDriver                    0x1d54e5ed8 (Missing)
2  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib     0x1d0eb6fac gpusSubmitDataBuffers
3  AGXGLDriver                    0x1d54e7404 (Missing)
4  WebCore                        0x1beb39e30 WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::reshape(int, int) + 580
5  WebCore                        0x1bf001758 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::initializeNewContext() + 936
6  WebCore                        0x1bf001048 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::WebGLRenderingContextBase(WebCore::CanvasBase&, WTF::Ref<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D> >&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 640
7  WebCore                        0x1beff7c3c WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::create(WebCore::CanvasBase&, WTF::Ref<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D> >&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 84
8  WebCore                        0x1bf0003fc WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::create(WebCore::CanvasBase&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes&, WTF::String const&) + 1416
9  WebCore                        0x1be6cfd6c WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement::getContext(JSC::ExecState&, WTF::String const&, WTF::Vector<JSC::Strong<JSC::Unknown>, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>&&) + 904
10 WebCore                        0x1bdc59194 WebCore::jsHTMLCanvasElementPrototypeFunctionGetContext(JSC::ExecState*) + 416
11 JavaScriptCore                 0x1bc33073c llint_entry + 89260
12 JavaScriptCore                 0x1bc32ecb4 llint_entry + 82468
13 JavaScriptCore                 0x1bc32ed54 llint_entry + 82628
14 JavaScriptCore                 0x1bc32ed54 llint_entry + 82628
15 JavaScriptCore                 0x1bc31a7fc vmEntryToJavaScript + 268
16 JavaScriptCore                 0x1bc84b32c JSC::Interpreter::executeProgram(JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 9816
17 JavaScriptCore                 0x1bca546dc JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 320
18 WebCore                        0x1be30d4bc WebCore::JSExecState::profiledEvaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 108
19 WebCore                        0x1be30d2f8 WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld&, WebCore::ExceptionDetails*) + 232
20 WebCore                        0x1be5af98c WebCore::ScriptElement::executeClassicScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 640
21 WebCore                        0x1be5774c8 WebCore::LoadableClassicScript::execute(WebCore::ScriptElement&) + 140
22 WebCore                        0x1be5afc30 WebCore::ScriptElement::executeScriptAndDispatchEvent(WebCore::LoadableScript&) + 224
23 WebCore                        0x1be5b2f40 WebCore::ScriptRunner::timerFired() + 508
24 WebCore                        0x1bea5a20c WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 216
25 WebCore                        0x1bea7a258 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28
26 CoreFoundation                 0x1b4f92650 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
27 CoreFoundation                 0x1b4f92380 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1b4f91bb4 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1b4f8cb04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1844
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1b4f8c0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
31 WebCore                        0x1bdc1cbd8 RunWebThread(void*) + 600
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4c1f2c0 _pthread_body + 128
33 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4c1f220 _pthread_start + 44
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b4c22cdc thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Some 3d web rendering fails, my guestimate is due to device running out of memory. Can you provide a sample minimalistic html that is being displayed?

Comment: Hi Kamil thank you. That's interesting, I have -webkit-transform : translate3d(0, 0, 0) and -webkit-transform-style : preserve-3d applied as CSS rules on the body element of the main WkWebView.

Comment: That itself^ doesn't look very heavyweight tbh , what is actually displayed on the page?

Comment: Looks like it's from AdMob interstitial ads https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/MOaVw22zUgY/sOCFi3TuBgAJ

Comment: And fixed in Admob iOS 7.45.0

Comment: please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/MOaVw22zUgY/sOCFi3TuBgAJ had a workaround but it was fixed in Admob iOS 7.45.0 https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes

> Fixed a crash that occurs on rare occasions when dismissing video ads.

Answer (score 2):

I faced these crashes, then switch to using WKWebView. WKWebViews run in another process, so even if this issue still occurs it may crash only the web view instead of the entire application.

put this key in your infor.plist should do it

```
<key>gad_preferred_webview</key>

<string>wkwebview</string>
```